# How to read data from file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this program to take properties from a data file and input them into calculations into the program. this is my code at the moment but it isn't taking any values into it.. any help is appreciated

```
float woodcharacStrength(){
    myInfile.open ("strength_classes.txt");     //inputs external file that contains characteristic values for forces parallel to grain.

    for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
        for (col = 0; col<18; col++)            //condition to only read certain rows and columns of the input file
        {
myInfile >> arraylocation[row][col];        //used to define each value of the array
        }

switch(woodType){
    case 'A':
    case 'a': ftk = arraylocation[0][0]; fck = arraylocation[1][0];break;
    case 'B':
    case 'b': ftk = arraylocation[0][1]; fck = arraylocation[1][1];break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c': ftk = arraylocation[0][2]; fck = arraylocation[1][2];break;
    case 'D':
    case 'd': ftk = arraylocation[0][3]; fck = arraylocation[1][3];break;
    case 'E':
    case 'e': ftk = arraylocation[0][4]; fck = arraylocation[1][4];break;
    case 'F':
    case 'f': ftk = arraylocation[0][5]; fck = arraylocation[1][5];break;
    case 'G':
    case 'g': ftk = arraylocation[0][6]; fck = arraylocation[1][6];break;
    case 'H':
    case 'h': ftk = arraylocation[0][7]; fck = arraylocation[1][7];break;
    case 'I':
    case 'i': ftk = arraylocation[0][8]; fck = arraylocation[1][8];break;
    case 'J':
    case 'j': ftk = arraylocation[0][9]; fck = arraylocation[1][9];break;
    case 'K':
    case 'k': ftk = arraylocation[0][10]; fck = arraylocation[1][10];break;
    case 'L':
    case 'l': ftk = arraylocation[0][11]; fck = arraylocation[1][11];break;
    case 'M':
    case 'm': ftk = arraylocation[0][12]; fck = arraylocation[1][12];break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n': ftk = arraylocation[0][13]; fck = arraylocation[1][13];break;
    case 'O':
    case 'o': ftk = arraylocation[0][14]; fck = arraylocation[1][14];break;
    case 'P':
    case 'p': ftk = arraylocation[0][15]; fck = arraylocation[1][15];break;
    case 'Q':
    case 'q': ftk = arraylocation[0][16]; fck = arraylocation[1][16];break;
    case 'R':
    case 'r': ftk = arraylocation[0][17]; fck = arraylocation[1][17];break;
}

    cout <<"The ftk value is: "<< ftk<< endl<<"The fck value is: "<< fck<<endl;

    return ftk;
    return fck;

    myInfile.close();
}
```

Comment: The program flow ends in the first return. Place the file close before the return. Also, you're not doing anything with the switch.

Comment: Sorry im new to c++ i dont really understand.. ill post more of the code up would be grateful for any comments

Comment: You have two `return` statements in a row.  Execution comes to the first `return` statement and returns from the function.  Thus the 2nd `return` and the `fclose` will never be executed.  You compiler should have caught this.  Turn up the warning level to maximum.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (row = 0; row<3; row++) //you have no open and close braces for this for loop
```

Comment: It doesn't look like they are needed.  I don't think that `switch` is meant to be part of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:
1) Look up `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` so you don't have to use both upper and lower case letters in your `case` statements.

2) Create a index by subtracting letters:

```
unsigned int index = std::toupper(woodType) - 'A';
ftk = arraylocation[0][index];
fck = arraylocation[1][index];
```

3) A function can only return one value:  `ftk` or `fck`.
If you want to return more than one value, pass them by reference or put them in a structure and return a copy of the modified structure.

4) No execution flows after a `return` statement, so your code will never execute the 2nd return statement or the `fclose`.

Comment: Don't forget to bounds-check the index.